# В чем ошибка в коде? Библиотека openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

**КОД:**

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.open('путь к файлу')

wb.active = 1
ws = wb.active

for row in ws.iter_rows('B4:F4'):
for cell in row:
if cell.value == "Анна":
print(ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=2).value)
```

Код выдает ошибку:
for row in range(min_row, max_row + 1):

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

*Код к этой таблице*

[image: Данный код к этой таблице]

Требуется найти ячейку со значением "Анна" и вывести в консоль

В чем состоит проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Если уж на то пошло, вам нужно провести итерацию по столбцам а не по строкам.
Предлагаю такой вариант:

Если значения расположены в одной строке, то необходимо "пробежать" по столбцам и конкретной строке(в Вашем случае 4). Если данные расположены в нескольких строках, то можно использовать вложенный цикл.

пример для одной строки:

```
for col in range(2,ws.max_column + 1):
```

Пример для нескольких строк:

```
for row in range("начало отсчёта","конец отсчёта"):
    for col in range("начало отсчёта","конец отсчёта"):
        #условие
            print(ws.cell(row,col)
```

Далее определяем условия, обязательно делаем проверку на None:

```
if ws.cell(4,col).value is not None and ws.cell(4,col).value == 'Анна':
```

Ну и сам вывод:

```
print(ws.cell(4,col).value)
```

Полный код:

```
import openpyxl as op
wb = op.load_workbook("путь к файлу")
wb.active
ws = wb.active

for col in range(2,ws.max_column + 1):
    if ws.cell(4,col).value is not None and ws.cell(4,col).value == 'Анна':
        print(ws.cell(4,col).value)
```